# Matching dataframe with coordinates to shape file coordinate system

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that contains the geometry of the shape file for US states, because it is extremely long text I posted it at the bottom of the question. Now I also have a dataframe with the longitudes and latitudes of big cities in the US and I want to overlay this dataframe on a map. However, when I do so I see only one red dot. So I think there is something wrong with non-corresponding coordinate systems. Does someone know how to solve this? This is how I made the dataframe whit US cities:

```
states = st_read('/Users/roelalex/Desktop/Earth Surface and Water Master/THESIS/cb_2015_us_state_5m/cb_2015_us_state_5m.shp')
states.32119 = states %>% st_transform(32119)
statesShape = states.32119 %>% mutate(STATEFP= str_remove(GEOID, "^0+")) %>%
  select(STATEFP, NAME, geometry)
statesShape = statesShape[-c(3, 23, 33, 34, 41, 42, 43), ]
```

I got the shape file from [United States Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html). The cities dataframe looks as:

```
structure(list(city = c("New York", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", 
"Miami", "Dallas", "Philadelphia", "Houston", "Atlanta", "Washington", 
"Boston"), lng = c(-73.9249, -118.4068, -87.6862, -80.2102, -96.7662, 
-75.1339, -95.3889, -84.4224, -77.0163, -71.0846), lat = c(40.6943, 
34.1139, 41.8373, 25.7839, 32.7936, 40.0077, 29.7863, 33.7627, 
38.9047, 42.3188)), row.names = c(13L, 28L, 50L, 94L, 108L, 112L, 
120L, 121L, 125L, 160L), class = "data.frame")
```

And finally, I used this code to plot everything:

```
test_plot = ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=statesShape) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "white")) +
  geom_point(data = us_big_cities, aes(x = lng, y = lat), color = 'red')
test_plot
```

**ANSWER**
The key is to use this code:

```
crs= 4326
usbigcities_test = st_as_sf(usbigcities_test, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)
usbigcities_test = st_transform(usbigcities_test, crs = crs)
```

And then plot it with:

```
test_plot = ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=statesShape) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "white")) +
  geom_sf(data = usbigcities_test, color = 'red')
test_plot
```

Comment: A larger code snippet would help. Maybe include the ggplot() code you are using to make this map?

Comment: I think a larger snippet from one or two cities/states would be sufficient. I don't think we can currently do anything with the code and output information that you provided besides making assumptions of what your ggplot() code might look like (Is that the intention?). The data structure code for the data frame with the cities is also missing the beginning part. Please include the ggplot() code that you are using/attempting to make this map.

Comment: I added a few pieces of code above, thanks for the tips.

Comment: I solved it by using this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55221669/maps-with-r-cant-change-the-projection-for-points-coordinates